# SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid + setTcpNoDelay

Tags: socketexception

I'm getting following error in my socket programming, please help me to identify the root cause of this error.

> SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid.
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketNativeSetOption(Native Method)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:597)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.setOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:340)
>       at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:894) 
>       at com.TestSocket.run(TestSocket.java:112)

Comment: Can you add the code that is causing this error please

Comment: What parameter is passed

Comment: Code Snippet:ServerSocket localSocket = new ServerSocket (7176);
 localSocket.setSoTimeout (500);
 Socket foreignSocket = localSocket.accept ();
 foreignSocket.setKeepAlive (true);
 foreignSocket.setReceiveBufferSize (2048);
 foreignSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
 foreignSocket.setSoTimeout (500);
 foreignSocket.setTcpNoDelay (false);